# MVC 3 Remote Validation Form Button Not Included in POST Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 app and with remote validation on one of my model classes. I discovered if I open the Edit view for the that model and the remote validation routine **IS NOT** called (due to not editing the field with remote validation on it) before submitting the form, the button clicked to POST the form **IS NOT** included in the request data sent to the Action method.

If the remote validation routine **IS** called before the form is POSTed - the button clicked to submit the form **IS** included in the POST.

I need to know which button was clicked when the Action is called on the server so I can determine if the user clicked UPDATE or CANCEL.

If I remove the remote validation from the model the form submits correctly every time.

Why would the button that was used to submit the form be excluded from the form post when remote validation is not called prior to the form submission.

thanks
Michael

Here is some sample code:

```
@model Channel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Channel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChannelGUID)


    <div class="editor-label">Name</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">Description</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">Channel Code</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
    </div>

    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="updateCommand" value="Update">Update</button>
        <button type="submit" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

here is the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string updateCommand, Channel channel)
{
    if (updateCommand != null)
    {
     //update clicked
    }
    else
    {
     //cancel clicked
    }
```

here is the remote attribute on the model property Code

```
[Remote("IsChannelCodeUnique", "Channel", AdditionalFields = "ChannelGUID", ErrorMessage = "code must be unique")]
```

Comment: Can you share your markup for the button in your view?

Comment: <button type="submit" name="updateCommand" value="Update">Update</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to changing the cancel button to a link (using an action link) and using jQuery UI to to style the link and the submit button on the form to look the same. This avoids the issues that I was having with the clicked button not being included in the POST data. Now when the action is called I do not need to determine the button that was clicked to see if the user pressed cancel.

Comment: Can you post your solution? I am having an issue with Remote Validation and multiple buttons in MVC3:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093088/multiple-submit-buttons-in-mvc3-formcollection-has-no-key-value-for-input-type)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue. I added remote validation to a form that had two submit inputs and the value of the submit button that was clicked, was *not always* posted any more.

While the other answers provide work-arounds, I delved it bit deeper and will answer the actual question you asked: *"Why would the button that was used to submit the form be excluded from the form post when remote validation is not called prior to the form submission."*

I knew that a [Javascript Submit does not include the Submit Button Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709301/javascript-submit-does-not-include-submit-button-value). Therefore, I tried to post with javascript disabled. Validation didn't work, but the value of my submit was posted. I assumed that jquery.validate.js jumps in and sends a programmatic submit. This is indeed the case. This is what happens, using jquery.validate.js 1.9.0, uncompressed:

1. When the page is loaded, on line 942 the validators are extended with a *remote* method, and on line 735 with a *stopRequest* prototype.
2. Validation occurs when the input field looses focus for the first time, when you type in it after that or when you submit the form.
3. Upon validation, the *stopRequest* method is called.
4. When the a submit input is clicked, submission is suppressed somehow. in line 56 there is a statement `event.preventDefault();`, but this is only called in debug mode. Anyway, the *stopRequest* method will be called when a submit was clicked and after the remote validation was performed.
5. When the form is valid, line 742 is called: `$(this.currentForm).submit();`, which is a programmatic submit and will not post the value of the submit. This is why I cannot determine which submit button was clicked.

Looking more carefully at the way the validation is extended, I found on line 59 the definition of a handler that seems to be designed to overcome some similar issue: It adds a hidden input with exactly the name and value of the submit button it handles. However, in my case neither `validator.settings.submitHandler` nor `validator.submitButton` are defined, so this code is never called.

It would have been nice if this hidden field were added in this case as well, since MVC will not know nor care what type of input posted the value and the post action on the controller could just use the value.

**Addition**
My workaround for the issue is adding a handler to the click functions of the submits:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    var hidden = $("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name", this.name).val(this.value).appendTo($(this).closest("form"));
});
```

The hidden field is created, so I do not have to rely on a hidden field with the correct name being present. 
You can either give your submits the same names, and test for the value, or give them different names and test for the presence of a post parameter. 
Of course, you would also need to use a form field name not already in use.

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking the hidden field should be removed and recreated (or updated) on subsequent clicks, especially when a different button was clicked. For example, if the first submit button click failed validation, subsequent submit button clicks will add another hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

We created a custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute so that it is not necessary to write if else or switch statements to decide which button was clicked. Here is the custom class:

```
public class AcceptParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var req = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

        return req.Form[this.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

This attribute selects the method to be executed based on the name of the button that was clicked. And here is the usage:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName(ActionNameEditUser)]
[AcceptParameter(Name = "save")]
public ActionResult Save()
{
    // put your code here
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName(ActionNameEditUser)]
[AcceptParameter(Name = "cancel")]
public ActionResult Cancel()
{
    // put your code here
}
```

All what is left to name the buttons accordingly, and we are done:

```
<button name="save">Save</button>
<button name="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Although this is a pretty solution, it will not work when using remote validation the way it is done in the question, as not post data for the submit input is generated.