# Multiple Submit Buttons in MVC3 - FormCollection has no Key/Value for Input Type Submit - Remote Validation Issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the two buttons in MVC3 application.

```
   <input type="submit" name="command" value="Transactions" />  &nbsp;
   <input type="submit" name="command" value="All Transactions" />
```

When I click on a button, it posts back correctly but the FormCollection has no "command" keys.  I also added a property "command" in the model and its value is null when the form is posted.

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, SearchReportsModel searchReportsModel).         {
            if (searchReportsModel.command == "All Transactions")
              ...
            else
              ....
        }
```

I am using IE8. How can I use multiple buttons in MVC3?  Is there a workaround for this issue? I did lot of research and could not find a solution.
Update:

Dave: I tried your solution and it is throwing Http 404 error "The resource cannot be found".

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptSubmitType(Name = "Command", Type = "Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index(SearchReportsModel searchReportsModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Transactions", "Reports", new { ...});
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptSubmitType(Name = "Command", Type = "All Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index_All(SearchReportsModel searchReportsModel)
{
   return RedirectToAction("AllTransactions", "Reports", new { ... });
}

public class AcceptSubmitTypeAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext
                .Request.Form[this.Name] == this.Type;
        }
    }
```

The issue was resolved after commenting the following Remote validation attribute in the ViewModel (SearchReportsModel). It looks like it is a bug in MVC3:

```
  //[Remote("CheckStudentNumber", "SearchReports", ErrorMessage = "No records exist for this Student Number")]
  public int? StudentNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why use `FormCollection` *and* what appears to be a view model? Have you tried with just the view model? It should bind.

Comment: Yes, I tried with ViewModel first with no luck. Then I added FormCollection to see if I can get key/value for "command".   ViewModel has this property: public string command { get; set; }

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem!  Was the solution really to remove your [Remote] validation from one of the form inputs?  That sucks!  I really need my [Remote] validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to get away with an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx) and override the IsValidForRequest method. You can see below this method just determines whether a particular parameter (Name) matches one of it's properties (Type). It should bind with a view model that looks like this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string command { get; set; }
    public string moreProperties { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute could look like this:

```
public class AcceptSubmitTypeAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext
            .Request.Form[this.Name] == this.Type;
    }
}
```

Then, you could tag your actions with the `AcceptSubmitType` attribute like this:

```
[AcceptSubmitType(Name="command", Type="Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel vm) 
{
    // use view model to do whatever
}

// to pseudo-override the "Index" action
[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptSubmitType(Name="command", Type="All Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index_All(TestViewModel vm) 
{
    // use view model to do whatever
}
```

This also eliminates the need for logic in a single controller action since it seems you genuinely need two separate courses of action.

Comment: I was able to confirm that it will bind with a view model. I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried your solution and it is throwing Http 404 error "The resource cannot be found".

Here is my code:
[HttpPost]
[AcceptSubmitType(Name = "Command", Type = "Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index(SearchReportsModel searchReportsModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Transactions", "Reports", new { ...});
}
       
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptSubmitType(Name = "Command", Type = "All Transactions")]
public ActionResult Index_All(SearchReportsModel searchReportsModel)
{
   return RedirectToAction("AllTransactions", "Reports", new { ... });

Comment: @rk1962 You have to be kidding me. Please edit your OP and add that code. My brain cannot parse it as a comment.

Comment: I just updated it. Sorry, I could not format it in the comments section.  Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: @rk1962 Please be more specific. What is "it" that is "throwing" a 404? Do you hit breakpoints when debugging? The request to `Index`, `Index_All`, or some further request after RedirectToAction? Do the `Transactions` and `AllTransactions` actions exist in your Reports controller?

Comment: When I click a button (Transactions or All Transactions), it is throwing 404 error. Yes, I did set the breakpoint on both Index and Index_All methods and the control did not reach any of these methods after exiting the AcceptSubmitTypeAttribute method. Both Transactions and AllTransactions do exist in the Reports controller.

Comment: @rk1962 And when debugging the attribute, what is the value of `Name` and `Type`? I've confirmed this works, so maybe something is wrong in your form. Check the `Request.Form` collection when debugging.

Comment: The value of Name and Type are "Command","Transactions", "All Transactions" in the AccepSubmitTypeAttribute method.  It was throwing error after exiting this method.  I set the breakpoint on the control methods and it did not reach the breakpoint at all.

Comment: I figured it out. The following Remote attribute is causing this issue: `[Remote("CheckStudentNumber", "SearchReports", ErrorMessage = "No records exist for this Student Number")].` Your Solution works great after commenting this line. It might be a bug in MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me If I'm wrong, but according to W3C standard you should have only 1 submit button per form. Also having two controls with identical names is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

when you submit (on any button) your whole page is posted back to the controller action, I have had the same problem but have not found a decent solution yet.. maybe you could work with a javascript 'onclick' method and set a hidden value to 1 for the first button and 0 for the second button or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice Blog about this found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx)

I like the look of adding in `AcceptParameterAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

@CodeRush: The W3C standard **does** allow more than 1 submit per form.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html. "A form may contain more than one submit button".