# Multiple Submit buttons in Form neither appearing in FormCollection of ASP.Net MVC Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm at my wits end here...I have the following razor markup for my form:

```
<input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Post" name="SubmitButton" />
<input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Save" name="SubmitButton" />
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the FormCollection parameter of the controller action method does not include SubmitButton in its Key/Value pairs.

I've come across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093088/multiple-submit-buttons-in-mvc3-formcollection-has-no-key-value-for-input-type) that seems to have had the same problem.  The solution seemed to be to use a ActionMethodSelectorAttribute AND to remove the use of [Remote] validation.  But I really need my [Remote] validator though, so it is not an option for me to remove that.  Is there no other solution, or is this some bug I just have to deal with?

I'm thinking along the lines of having to replace my use of two buttons with a single Save button, and then add a "Post" checkbox.  Then in the controller action I check for the presence of the Post KeyValue pair.  But this is less than idea.  I prefer the use of two buttons.

EDIT: more view markup following Igor's request:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit details for Client Warehouse Request </legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelObject.CustomerCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelObject.ReqNr)

        <div style="table-layout: initial;">
            <div class="columnDivider">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelObject.ReqNr)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModelObject.ReqNr)
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelObject.CreationDate)
                </div>
                ... many other fields following the above structure...
                <input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Post" name="SubmitButton" />
                <input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Save" name="SubmitButton" />
            </div> 
            <div class="columnDivider">
               ...some more fields
            </div>
            <div>
               Here I have a Kendo UI datagrid that gets submitted with the form
            </div>
      </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: can you show view markup (simplified if possible) of the form and the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SubmitButtonValue" id="SubmitButtonValue" />

<input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Post" name="SubmitButton" />
<input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Save" name="SubmitButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".k-button").click(function(){
      $("#SubmitButtonValue").val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

and check for `"SubmitButtonValue"` key in `FormCollection`.