# HTML Form Button value is not posted in Safari and Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I am using jQuery to submit a form when a button is clicked. I would then like to test the value of the button, however, this doesn't get submitted in Safari and Chrome. Why? Is there a work around?

Test the following code in IE/FF to see that it works, and then test it in Safari/Chrome to see that it does not:

**ButtonPostTest.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['testBtn'])) {
        echo $_POST['testBtn'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#btn').click(function() {
                    $('form').submit();  // submit the form
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">          
            <button id="btn" class="page-btn" type="submit" name="testBtn" value="Yes Button value is posted!">POST IT!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

The same thing happens with `input`:

```
<input id="btn" class="page-btn" type="submit" name="testBtn" value="Post this"></input>
```

Also, this is only an issue when submitting using jQuery `.submit()`- without this, it submits fine with either the button or input.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. Was driving me crazy, didn't even suspect the jquery.submit I had added earlier... I found this explanation of the behavior and why it happens: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709352/76672

Comment: Seems to work ok in Chrome (Linux Mint). It has been using a fork of Webkit for quite some time now so perhaps it's fixed in Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

Give it a name.

```
<button type='submit' id='trash' name='trash' value="trash" class='red'>
```

Answer (score 3):

As Robert says above when using the `<button>` tag you need both `name=""` and `value=""`, e.g.

```
<button name="Search" value="Simple" type="submit">Search</button>
```

VS

```
<button name="Search" value="Advanced" type="submit">Search</button>
```

In this example your POST data would have the ***Key*** Value pair of:

***Search** Simple*

or

***Search** Advanced*

And then based on that POST value you can write your code to take the appropriate action. :)

**i.e. you don't need to use input, just use button with name/value and you'll be fine.**

Answer (score 3):

#### Button disabled during submit/click event doesn't submit its value

As per Alan Stewart, I had this problem introduced when I wrote a little utility to prevent double-clicking a form submit button which listened for "submit" and disabled the button.

I changed my code so it determines if the form has already been submitted, and if so, disables the button and prevents the form submitting via `event.preventDefault()`.

It's not as nice as before which immediately disabled the button which gave instant visual feedback (since Bootstrap has a style for disabled buttons).

Answer (score 2):

I think you've discovered a webkit bug.

I get the same thing testing in Chrome, your form:

```
<form action="" method="post">          
   <button id="btn" class="page-btn" type="submit" name="testBtn" value="Yes Button value is posted!">POST IT!</button>
</form>
```

This sends no data. If' however I add another element, an input in particular:

```
<form action="" method="post">          
   <input type="hidden" name="shim" value="" />
   <button id="testBtn" class="page-btn" type="submit" name="testBtn" value="Yes Button value is posted!">POST IT!</button>
</form>
```

This sends both values. This is without the JavaScript. Once you add the shim hidden form element, it looks like it gets sense.

This solution needs more testing, but it may address your need.

Comment: I need to use jQuery to submit so that i can alter the form action before submitting. Still the same result (when submitting using jQuery)...

Comment: I'm not sure that makes a difference. The point of the shim is that I think Chrome may behave differently based on the number and type of form elements in a form.

Answer (score 1):

How many values are you POSTing?

I'm not sure it sounds like your problem was solved. One thing that has not been mentioned is that **you may have overshot your php max_input_vars limit.**

Php is silent when you overshoot this limit, so you'll have to check the warning log, or check it this way:

1.
Count the POST array values. Scripting in `var_dump($_POST);` (in a safe production sandbox environment) will do this best, as you can look at the final value output to see where the POST array "cuts off".

2.
Next, run a script to output the php information using the function: `phpinfo()`. Check the value of "max_input_vars".

3.
If the POST array count == the "max_input_vars" value, then you have overshot the limit.

In your case, it may be the case that the submit input would have been included later in the POST.

To edit the value (to 5000 in this example) in php.ini, add or edit this line: `max_input_vars = 5000`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably super obvious and now that I fixed it on my own I realize was a stupid mistake.  But for me, I had mistakenly left off `type="submit"`.  Form always worked, but just posted a value from those buttons.

**No value passed (bad):**

```
<button name="step" id="btn1" value="my_value">btn_text</button>
```

**Value passes (good):**

```
<button type="submit" name="step" id="btn1" value="my_value">btn_text</button>
```

Anyway, I hope this helps someone new that is starting out, or stuck on something that seems so obvious.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So, I had a very similar thing happen to me.  Everything works, except in Chrome [Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)].

When I took out the id= in my <button>, it worked!  But that was NOT the problem.  The problem turned out to be that I am disabling the [Submit] button at onclick= in the <button> tag (using the button id=).  When you do this, Chrome appears to just not post anything.  Which is kinda pointless?  And weird?  And I have no idea why?

So I spent a huge bunch of time digging around and found out that you CAN disable the [Submit] button at onsubmit= in the <form>.  In fact, onsubmit= is almost the same as onclick= so in the future I think I need to just change things so that I always use onsubmit= and then ALL the big browsers will continue to work for me.

Comment: I can report the same issue. I'm disabling the button during a submit event handler in order to prevent double-submits.

Comment: I can also report that I was disabling it during onsubmit, so the fix alluded to (instead of onclick, use onsubmit) wasn't right for me. I've added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` and `<input>` are two different tag. If you want to submit your button values then use `<input>` tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, it produces the same result :(

Comment: Hello Mike I got your problem. I want to know why you're using jquery to submit the form? If you directly submit the form without jQuery you'll get the submit button value. But if you take help of javascript it wont submit the buttons value.

Comment: I am using jQuery to submit the form because I have multiple submit buttons in the form and i want to alter the form action before it is submitted - depending on which button is clicked.

Comment: Okay... Then I'll suggest you to set a hidden field and overwrite its value based on the button is clicked. Then you can easily identify which button was pressed on server side.

Comment: Button elements are functionally the same as input[type="submit"] except they are rendered with richer markup.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Vins, I'd probably use `<input>`.

Is there a particular reason why you are using `<button>` instead of `<input>`? I typically prefer `<button>` (allows me to add icons and images), but I believe there are differences between browsers regarding how value is interpreted...

According to <s>[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp)</s> [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button#Notes), some browsers will submit the value attribute, while other browsers such as IE7 will incorrectly submit the text between the tags.

Comment: If you really need a `<button>` for display purposes you can work around the problem with a JS click handler that sets the appropriate value in a hidden field...

Comment: Changing button to input does not work either, it is still not submitted. The hidden field is submitted, so i may have to go with this work around option -> on button click, set hidden field to appropriate value, then submit the form, use the hidden field for processing. I just wonder if there is a better solution?

Comment: I will no longer reference w3schools. I will no longer reference w3schools. I will no longer reference w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to send a button as submit by catching a hidden input.

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btname']))
        echo $_POST['btname'];
    }
 ?>
```

and html:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="formname" name="formname">
<input name="btname" id="btname" type="hidden" />
<button onclick="document.formname.submit()" value="Submit">Send</button>
</form>
```