# Passing values from javascript to form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button (input type=button)that toggles through 3 states using a bit of simple
bit of javascript, this works well but I find that when I submit the form I cant pass
the current value of the button.

```
<input type=button ID="1" value="$decMake" name=decMake onclick="toggle(this);">
```

The JS:

```
function toggle(button) {
  if(document.getElementById("1").value==""){
    document.getElementById("1").value="Strength";
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("1").value=="Strength"){
    document.getElementById("1").value="Opportunity";
  }
  else if(document.getElementById("1").value=="Opportunity"){
    document.getElementById("1").value="";
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do this with a simple input "hidden" statement but I think this is not
enough and needs to be a bit cleverer then that, whats the best way of doing this

Thanks

Comment: valid HTML IDs may not start with numbers.

Comment: @jbabey I thought they can in HTML5...

Comment: @jbabey, [as per the HTML5 spec: "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters."](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-id-attribute). IDs are no longer restricted from starting with a number, browsers have always supported them that way because developers are unreliable.

Comment: @Ian yes, i suppose if you're only developing for the latest browsers then you could make the ID whatever you want. In most cases you are developing for all browsers and you literally lose nothing by making your IDs HTML4 compliant.

Comment: @Ian - even so, for compatibility do you really want to mix up html5 with legacy?

Comment: Related *(to the question, not the ID discussion)*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381110/1917390

Comment: @jbabey That's not my point. You claimed they aren't valid. They are in HTML5. That's all I'm saying. Not arguing whether it's right to do this or not, but that's not what your comment was about

Comment: @Jimmmy Again, not my point. The comment had nothing to do with being "right", it had to do with validity. HTML5 supports it, so you can't just claim it's wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hidden input is probably the best way to do this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="buttonValue" value=""/>
<input type=button ID="buttonToggle" value="$decMake" name="buttonToggle" onclick="toggle(this);">
```

Also change the button `id` to something more descriptive.

```
function toggle(button) {
    var value=button.value;
    switch(value){
        case "": value="Strength"; break;
        case "Strength": value="Opportunity"; break;
        default : value=""; 
    }
    button.value = value;
    document.getElementById("buttonValue").value = value;
}
```

Comment: Nice... I was justing looking if someone had done this already

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for that. normally I use an $input{'var_name'};

Comment: I'm not following.  PHP is not my language of choice.  However you want to set up the `id`s is fine. You can modify this JS to fit, or I can if you elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for that. normally I use an $input{'var_name'}; to get the value back into the form, is this the case here? Sorry I'm more html than javascript

Comment: Basically, all this does is copy the button value into a hidden input value. So when you post, you should be able to get it from the $input{'buttonValue'}  I would imagine. But like I said, php isn't my strong suit. The html should be easy to follow though.

Comment: Agree, that's what I was trying to do but the value isn't being posted back like I thought it should.

Comment: Finally got this going, needed to change buttonToggle to buttonValue