# Form submit button value SOMETIMES is not POSTed in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, post, button

**NOT** a duplicate of [HTML Form Button value is not posted in Safari and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380816/html-form-button-value-is-not-posted-in-safari-and-chrome)

I have a button that is used to submit a form when it is clicked.

```
<form method="post" action="<URL>" class="login_form" name="login_form" id"login_form">
    ... various inputs here ...
    <button type="submit" name="signIn" class="cta">
        <span class="arrow">Enter</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

The button **name** is used server-side to determine what action is to be taken  (**value** is not provided because it is not used by the server).

The problem is that **sometimes** the name is not posted to the server, while **sometimes** it is. The ratio is about 1miss/6hits.

Many other forms on my website have the same structure, but I found this behaviour only for this one.
It seems to happen only with Chrome.

I tried clicking the button right after the page is loaded and after having waited quite some time after the page is fully loaded. so it seems not to be tied to the rest of the page.

Is this a known bug or could this be caused by something else?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue and in my case it was due to a JavaScript that on Form-Submit disabled the Submit-Button (the intention of that is to prevent duplicate POSTs when users double-click).

Disabled form elements are not included in the formdata.

A better way to "disable" it for the intent of preventing double-clicks thus may be setting `pointer-events: none` or preventing the surplus submits in JS (`preventDefault`).

It may also explain that it worked "sometimes", as I imagine there is room for a race between gathering the formdata and the button becoming disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this kind of error occurs when there is a problem with the coding of the form itself, or some related javascript error.  The fact that you have tracked this to a 1 per 6 chance of happening supports this reasoning.  What I would suggest is to view your console output, turn on persistent logging, then submit your forms and test.  If this is indeed the problem, there will be some sort of error message printed on the console, and you will be able to solve the problem from there.

Comment: This is exactly i was going to post. An console error is way useful in this cases, maybe an alert/console-msg in every block can help to check in which one the process is getting the error, and check the exact error name.