# Whats the difference between onclick and onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onsubmit

It's not like I haven't googled it... But still I couldn't understand when `onsubmit` is used and when `onclick` is used?

Comment: Click could be anything, you can click pretty much any element.  On submit is for a form, and happens when a form is submitted.

Comment: If you hover over the `onclick` and `onsubmit` tags, it will give you a definition for each.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

They're two completely separate events.

`onclick` events fire when the user uses the mouse to click on something.

`onsubmit` events fire when a form is submitted. The origin of this event can sometimes be traced back to an `onclick` (like clicking the "submit" button) but it can also come from a keyboard event (like pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>).

This implies that using `onclick` on a submit button on a form might miss some cases that an `onsubmit` on the form would catch.

There are many other kinds of events such as: `onload` for loading resources such as scripts or images and `onkeydown` for detecting key presses on the keyboard.

Comment: So `onsubmit` is fired for both real form submissions and AJAX forms that have a submit button?

Comment: onsubmit is an event that can fire on a form. You can optionally `event.preventDefault()` and do an ajax call. There isn't anything special about _ajax_ forms.

Comment: More different is their behavior. `onsubmit` can't send button value but `onclick` can. Read more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709352/128761

Answer (score 9):

OnSubmit is used on a `form`, and indicates that the information is to be submitted to the server at this point unless you return false.

OnClick is used on anything, and indicates that it was clicked, offering no other context to the intention of the event at all.

Answer (score 4):

Onclick is the event where a control/object/pretty much anything, is clicked on. 
Onsubmit is the event where a form is submitted.

For example, lets say you have a registration form.

You can have the OnClick event of the "Submit" button to bring up an alert that says "Are you sure these details are correct?", and clicking "Ok" there can trigger the OnSubmit event, which would submit the form data to wherever you want it to go.

Answer (score 2):

In react as an example, onClick works on every element and it doesn't capture the full form event like "required".

```
     <form >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
          <button type="submit" onClick={myHandler} > Submit</button>
      </form>
```

In the case above, myHandler will execute without regarding the "required" property.

onSubmit, on the other hand, can capture all form events, for example, "required", but has to be applied to the form element itself.

```
      <form onSubmit={myHandler}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" required />
          <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Now, the required property works fine.

Answer (score -1):

onsubmit reference to form element and this event occurs when the form is submitted.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onsubmit

onclick reference to elements such as div, li etc, this event occurs when user clicks the element that attribute click is applied to.

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/onclick-html-attribute/