# Cannot POST / error when clicking Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova

I am developing a login page for our mobile app using Phone gap. But whenever I clicked the Submit button, an error 'Cannot POST /' appears. Why is that so? Please see my code below.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="main-info2">
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
            <div class="in-form">
                <form id="login_form" method="post"">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required=" " id="email" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required=" " id="password" />
                    <div class="check-sub">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copy-right">
            <p>Design by <a href="http://w3layouts.com">W3layouts</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //main -->
</body>
```

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    do_login();
});

function do_login() {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var dataString="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&login=";

        if($.trim(email).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:1234/cleverpro/login.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "success"){
                        console.log("hay nako!");
                        alert("hala");
                    }else if(data == "failed"){
                        $("#login").html('Login');
                        console.log("hastang sayupa");
                        alert("halajud");
                    }   
                }
            });
        }else{
            return false;
            console.log("walay sulod uy");
        }
    });
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include "db.php";

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])));
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password'])));
    $login=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from `user` where `email`='$email' and `password`='$password'"));

    if($login!=0){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }
}

?>
```

I didn't know where did I gone wrong with this. Please help me.

Comment: You have a trailing `"` after post, is that a typo?

Comment: Did you try to put all the code in one domain and see if it works?

Comment: hi. yeah it is a typo. I already removed it but still same error

Comment: hello @AlexOdenthal l what do you mean same domain? I am running it locally right now.

Comment: you have set an option called crossDomain: true in your ajax call which made me assume that you do crossDomain posts

Comment: @AlexOdenthal actually i'm new with this so I don't know what does that thing do :( but when I removes it, still it has the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would be better to use on('submit', handler) instead on click. (see [Whats the difference between onclick and onsubmit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762474/whats-the-difference-between-onclick-and-onsubmit))

When you clicks "Login", default form send action happens after your javascript code finishes. It means that form POST happens to 'action' of your form that is not set in your form and is '/' by default.

You need to preventDefault action, somethink like this

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: hello. I tried adding this and the error was gone but nothing happens, it doesn't alert .

Comment: ok so simply debug the stuff and see when it jumps out. just place a "console.log(i++);" after every line...and see what is the last number in the console. this should bring you to the problem line