# Submit a form from a link and get $_Post value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the following problem. I have a form containing several  links.
Those  links should assign a hidden field and submit the form using some javascript.

I'm using PHP 5.4.

When I submit the form using the button, the $_POST containts data. But when the form is submitter from javascript, the $_POST is empty.

Any clue?

```
<head>
   <script language="text/javascript">
    function affect(numMet)
    {
        document.forms['frmDemo'].num_met_choose.value = numMet;
        document.forms['frmDemo'].submit();
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
   var_dump($_POST);
  ?>

 <form name="frmDemo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <input  name="num_met_choose" id="num_met_choose">
   <a href="" onClick="javascript:affect('22');" >test 1</a>
   <a href="" onClick="javascript:affect('12');" >test 2</a>
   <button id="submit" type="submit">OK</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: where is  `action` form?

Comment: if no action the form will submit to itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709301/javascript-submit-does-not-include-submit-button-value

Comment: Yep, I made the most simplified sample to find the problem. In this case, I know I submit myself, and I would like to view the $_POST content... it's always empty when using <a> and filled when using the submit buttons...

Comment: @ashkufaraz Thank you, it explain why I'm having this problem!

Comment: I edited your post to remove the thanking and the signature. These should not be included in your post, see here why: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Where's that hidden field in your markup? Can you share the code in question?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

The first is this:

```
document.forms['frmDemo'].submit();
```

combined with this:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit">OK</button>
```

By having a form control with `id="submit"` inside the form, you overwrite the `submit` property of the the form object. Instead of being a function that you can call, it becomes a reference to the element with the id `submit`.

You need to use a different id (or none at all since you don't seem to be using it for anything).

You should have got an error in your browser's JavaScript console. Do keep and eye on that when your JS isn't behaving as you expect.

Even if you fix that, you have another problem:

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript:affect('22');" >test 1</a>
```

1. The JavaScript runs
2. The form is about to submit
3. The link is followed so the form isn't submitted after all

Don't use a link as a thing to run JS (unless you want it to function as a link, or are setting it up to use the link as a fallback).

Use a button (with `type="button"`) instead.

---

That said. Don't use JavaScript at all for this. You can get the same effect with plain HTML.

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="num_met_choose" value="22">test 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="num_met_choose" value="12">test 2</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="text"  name="num_met_choose" id="num_met_choose">
   <button type="submit" formaction="/action_page.php">Submit using 
   link</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <head>
   <script language="text/javascript">
    function affect(numMet)
    {
        //document.forms['frmDemo'].num_met_choose.value = numMet;
        //document.forms['frmDemo'].submit();
        document.getElementById("num_met_choose").value=numMet;
        document.getElementById("frmDemo").submit();
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
   var_dump($_POST);
  ?>

 <form name="frmDemo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <input  name="num_met_choose" id="num_met_choose">
   <a href="#" onClick="affect('22');" >test 1</a>
   <a href="#" onClick="affect('12');" >test 2</a>
   <button id="submit" type="submit">OK</button>
 </form>
```

Try this and let me know what is the outcome.

Comment: Exactly the same... I also displayed : <?php
 var_dump($_GET);
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
 var_dump($_POST);
?>
And it's empty when I click on the link. And filled when I click on the button...

Comment: "stackoverflow mentality" you try and help a person with your input but get down voted. Even though it was wrong it was an attempt to help. But obviously this is not a site you come to to get "help".