# jQuery dialog box for Form submit Or not

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQuery dialog box for confirmation, whether to `Submit` form or `Not`
I'm doing some validations before submitting form. When I click Submit button it first alerts **End**, which is at the end of submit button click handler and my validation fails
following is my code snippet

```
$('#id-submit-btn').click( function( event ) {
    //var $this = $(this);
    var submit = true;
    if( !$('.class-employees-cb:checked').length ) {
        $("<div title='Employee Selection'>Please select at least one employee.</div>").dialog({
            buttons: [ { text: 'OK', click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } } ]
        });
        submit = false;
        //event.preventDefault();
        //alert("2");
    }
    if( $('input:checkbox[name=isPrepondPostpond]').is(':checked') ) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        $("<div title='Prepond/Postpond Alert'>Have You Changed Meeting Date before Prepond / Postpond ?</div>").dialog({
            buttons:[
                {
                    text: 'Yes',
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $('#id-submit-btn').submit();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'No',
                    click: function() {
                        submit = false;
                        //event.preventDefault();
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        //alert("5");
    }
    alert("End");
    //event.preventDefault();
    if( !submit )
        return false;
});
```

I want to Prevent form Submission **if User Click NO**, how to achieve that?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` button. Also `return submit` is enough. I however STRONGLY recommend to use the form's submit event and use preventDefault if errors. Also do NOT call anything "submit" in the form

Comment: I will try and let u know

Comment: I replaced `$('#id-submit-btn').click(function( event ) { ` to `$('#id-submit-form').submit( function( event ) { `, but it does not wait for me to click on dialog box's button, it directly submits the form,  Also uncomment `event.preventDefault();` if validation fails

Comment: `$('#id-submit-form').on("submit", function( event ) {event.preventDefault();   .... })`

Comment: Also ` $('#id-submit-form').submit();` on the ok button

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
$('#id-submit-form').on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // cancel the submission
  if (!$('.class-employees-cb:checked').length) {
    $("<div title='Employee Selection'>Please select at least one employee.</div>").dialog({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }]
    });
  }
  if ($('input:checkbox[name=isPrepondPostpond]').is(':checked')) {
    $("<div title='Prepond/Postpond Alert'>Have You Changed Meeting Date before Prepond / Postpond ?</div>").dialog({
      buttons: [{
          text: 'Yes',
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $('#id-submit-form')[0].submit(); // submit the form
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'No',
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: i will try this one

Comment: It will only work if you do NOT have `name="submit"` somewhere

Comment: is this ok if I use dynamic dialog box like, `$("<div title='Employee Selection'>Please select at least one employee.</div>").dialog({})`

Comment: `It will only work if you do NOT have name="submit" somewhere`, what will happen then, bcoz I Got problem with `<input type='submit' name='isSave'>` parameter **isSave** is not passed

Comment: Name=submit is a problem - any other name not. Add a value if you want to pass something

Comment: I have `value="Update"`, but this one is also not passed

Comment: I cannot tell without seeing the HTML

Comment: this is my input Submit button, `<input type="submit" value="${ (meetingSchedule.meetingId == null ) ? 'Submit' : 'Update' }" id="id-submit-btn" name="isSave" class="submit_bt_WOD">`, **Right now value=Update**

Comment: Is it inside the form? I cannot tell without seeing the HTML

Comment: yes it is inside form,  **Generated HTML is**, `<input type="submit" value="Update" id="id-submit-btn" name="isSave" class="submit_bt_WOD">`

Comment: then is should be passed. I only have your word for the placement. Perhaps spelling on the server? Any console errors?

Comment: no Previously it was working, Actually when submitting through `JavaScript` Submit button is not serialized, Have a look   http://api.jquery.com/serialize/  **Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.**

Comment: I see. So you need a hidden field for the isSave - there is no serialisation going on here according to your code - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709313/295783

Comment: I'm not able to submit form, if no error, since `event.preventDefault();` is first line, To make it work, Do I need to copy `line`, to `if()` statement ?

Comment: `$('#id-submit-form')[0].submit();` submits the form WITHOUT the event handler. That is how you need to submit in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138787/discussion-between-shantaram-t-and-mplungjan).