# Using Jquery Validator and Sweetalert for Form Submission Confirmation Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, sweetalert

I am trying to do the following.

I have 3 buttons, "Continue", "Delete", "New". All of these are type "submit" buttons.

When the form is posted, the value of these buttons is used to determine what happens on the backend.

I want a Sweetalert popup to confirm if the user wants to delete, then when the OK button is hit, the form should progress and submit to the backend.

The issue I currently have is that there is no way to get the value of the submit button to the server side when I incorporate Sweetalert to show when I hit the submit button.

Scenario A) For example, if I remove the "e.preventDefault" from the callback, the alert popups for a brief second but the form submits, not giving the user to confirm or cancel the deletion. This is not correct behaviour, but the "submit" button value does indeed get posted to the server. So to prevent the quick popup issue, I add "e.preventDefault" to stop the normal behaviour of "submit" button.

Scenario B) However, when I have the code as below (i.e. "e.preventDefault" added to the code), the form does not submit after validation. Instead I have to run "$('#myForm').submit()". But when I do this, the value of the "submit" button does not get posted to the server.

If someone could kindly guide me on how I can use jQuery Validate and Sweetalert, it would be much appreciated.

An example of the set up looks like this:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm" action="/postHere" method="post">        
   <!-- Options-->
 <div class="row-select"> 
   <label for="options">My Options</label> 
    <select name="options" id="options">
      <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Select an Option</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
 </div>

  <!-- continue details form -->
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="continue" name="submitButton" value="Continue this Option">            
  </div> 

  <!-- delete details -->
  <div>          
    <input class="delete" type="submit" id="delete" name="submitButton" value="Delete this Option">                      
  </div>

  <!-- new -->  
  <div class="row-spaced">        
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Neither" formnovalidate>        
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var continueOption = document.getElementById('continue');
  var deleteOption = document.getElementById('delete');
  var neither = document.getElementById('new');

  $('#myForm').validate({
    ignore:'',
    rules: {
      options: "required"
    },

  });

  // AIM IS TO SHOW A CONFIRMATION BOX IF DELETE IS CLICKED
  if(deleteOption) {
    deleteOption.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
      })
      .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            console.log("here");
          $('#myForm').submit();
        }
      }); 
    });  
  }  
}

myFunction();
```

Backend Illustration:

```
router.post("/postHERE", (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.submitButton == "Continue this Option") {
        // Do something CONTINUE
    }
    else if (req.body.submitButton == "Delete this Option") {
        // Do something DELETE
    }
    else {
       // Do something NEW
    }
```

}

JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jintao/xpvt214o/935077/)

EDIT:

For the backend I am using Expressjs. I have added this in and fixed a type in the form method to be post.

Comment: What do you mean you want "the value of the submit button" to be sent to the server?  Typically, you would use your server-side code to get the ***unique*** `name` of the submit button from the POST array.  This has absolutely nothing to do with client-side JavaScript, popups or form validation.  (And you would use POST when sending data to the server, not GET.)

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin only knows it's triggered by a submit button, however, there is nothing in this plugin that identifies *which* submit button is used.  Again, you would need to look for the `name` of the button in the POST array on the server side, so every `button` should have a unique `name`, not all of them called `submitButton`.

Comment: Thanks  - what I meant is that i am using ExpressJS and want the value of the submit button to make it there. The submit button has a value that gets sent to the server. I parse this and it ends up in req.body as "req.body.submitButton". I then have a bit of logic that runs based on what value the "req.body.submitButton" has.

Comment: *"The submit button has a value that gets sent to the server."* ~ if the value is already sent to the server, then what is the problem?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: If you want to use the jQuery Validate plugin, then you absolutely should not be using `e.preventDefault()`.  The validation plugin already takes care of this part automatically.

Comment: Again, as I tried to explain before, the submit button, or any submit button inside the form, triggers the validation plugin.  Then after passing validation, the plugin submits the form.  Therefore, you do not have any control over the submit event because you've given this control over to the validation plugin.   Look at the POST array on the server for the `name` of the submit button.

Comment: Thanks - yes I refactored the code a bit using your suggestions. The issue was that when I removed `e.preventDefault()` (i.e. control was handed over to the validation plugin) the form would immediately submit if the user hit "Delete this Option" (when the select option had a valid value and passed validation). This meant that the user did not have time to confirm or cancel the delete action as the page would redirect immediately. So the `.then` bit of the `swal` promise was redundant. This can be replicated by commenting out `e.preventDefault()` and hitting "Delete this Option".

Comment: I guess my question really is. If I have 3 buttons, and I want to validate the input, and use Sweetalert to show a confirmation for Delete, but also keep track of which button was clicked, how can this be done?

I followed what you said (created 3 different names for each button) but for some reason I cannot get the unique name of the submit button in the POST array. 

I got around this by manually creating an AJAX call to my Nodejs backend, adding the button back to the data sent, when delete was triggered.

Comment: By "but for some reason I cannot get the unique name of the submit button in the POST array" I mean that the button isn't in the POST payload at all. I think it may be because I am submitting the form using javascript; `$('#myform').submit()`

Comment: [A potential answer to why javascript submit does not send the button payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709301/javascript-submit-does-not-include-submit-button-value)