# php pdo insert doesn't return

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to insert a form to the database using pdo. Everytime I click on submit, it seems it doesn't at all go though my function. I feel like I'm overlooking something (for 2 hours now).

The pdo connection works (it works in other files)

I cannot see my errors. Neither does any alert get echoed.

I feel like the problem lies here: `if(isset($_POST['insert'])){`

or with the `<input name="insert">` They just seem to be correct in my eyes.

Some help would be appreciated.

````
<form action="insertdata.php" method="post">

<div id="mainwrapper">
<input type="text" Placeholder="URL" name="url"><br>
<input type="text" Placeholder="Title" maxlength="40" name="title"><br>
<input type="textarea" Placeholder="Description" maxlength="200" name="description"><br>
<input type="text" Placeholder="Context" maxlength="25" name="location"><br>
<input id="submit" class="button" name="insert" type="submit" value="submit"></input>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// php insert data to mysql database using PDO

if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("test")</script>';


        // connect to pdo

    try{
        $pdoConnect = new pdo('pdo connection works correctly');
    }catch (PDOException $exc){
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
    }
    if(!$pdoConnect)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oups")</script>';

    }

    // get values form input text and number
    $url=$_POST['url'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    // mysql query to insert data
    if($url=="")
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You forgot something!")</script>';
    }

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `index` (`url`, `title`, `description`, `location`) VALUES (:url,:title,:description,:location)";



    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":url"=>$url,":title"=>$title,":description"=>$description,":location"=>$location));


        // check if mysql insert query successful
    if($pdoExec)
    {
        echo 'Thank you for submitting your website, you can now look for yourself';
    }else{
        echo 'Something went wrong, please contact us at a page we still need to make';
    }
}
?>
    </form>```
````

Comment: What happens if you use `if(isset($_POST['location'])){` ? Also discussed here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709301/javascript-submit-does-not-include-submit-button-value)

Comment: @RobMoll  noting interesting happens. Like, basically, the same thing.

Comment: Is it inserting or is it just not `echo`ing out the "Thank you"/"Something went wrong" messages?

Comment: @Edward It is neihter inserting nor is it echoing out anything. It feels as if all it does is refresh the page

Comment: Add this before `$pdoQuery` line: `$pdoConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Your form is calling `insertdata.php`, is this the current file ?

Comment: you are not posting any form field with the name "insert" or I am missing something?

Comment: @Nicolas Thats correct

Comment: @Edward, I have done so, nothing changed.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Tell me.. Because I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you for pointing it out. I removed it and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Form had an action that reloaded the page instead of running through the php function. I just had to remove it. Thank you  for your help

```
<form method="post">
^
|
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score -1):

I have copied your entire code and did run this. It works perfectly.

I think you have a problem with your table column datatypes. check whether you having all the columns in text or varchar datatype.

Here your code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<div id="mainwrapper">
<input type="text" Placeholder="URL" name="url"><br>
<input type="text" Placeholder="Title" maxlength="40" name="title"><br>
<input type="textarea" Placeholder="Description" maxlength="200" name="description"><br>
<input type="text" Placeholder="Context" maxlength="25" name="location"><br>
<input id="submit" class="button" name="insert" type="submit" value="submit"></input>

<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $pdoConnect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if (!$pdoConnect) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oups")</script>';

}

// get values form input text and number
$url         = $_POST['url'];
$title       = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$location    = $_POST['location'];
// mysql query to insert data
if ($url == "") {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You forgot something!")</script>';
}

$pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `index` (`url`, `title`, `description`, `location`) VALUES (:url,:title,:description,:location)";

$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(
    ":url" => $url,
    ":title" => $title,
    ":description" => $description,
    ":location" => $location
));


// check if mysql insert query successful
if ($pdoExec) {
    echo 'Thank you for submitting your website, you can now look for yourself';
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong, please contact us at a page we still need to make';
}

?>


</div>
</form>
```

And table:

```
CREATE TABLE `index` (
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: The OP specified `'pdo connection works correctly'` to hide his actual parameters for fear of revealing his user id/password, etc.